# how to choose folder with html input file

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I want to choose only folders when I'm clicking browse button. In my project I'm using IE for some reasons. I searched some forums but I didn't find any useful solution. After choosing a folder I want to show folder path in textbox. So is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The [`directory` attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-directory) is not supported in IE, and even where it is supported, the original *path* is not made available to JS.

Answer (score 0):

First, from the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory), we can see that the webkitdirectory attribute not support IE browser. So we can't use input file to select the folder.

Besides, when using the input file element to upload a file, most browsers (include the IE11 browser) will give you only the file name, instead of the full path. If we using the `value` attribute to get the file name, it will give us a fake path, like: "C:\fakepath\uploadfile.text". This is the browser default behavior, in order to prevent inappropriate information disclosure.

To get the full file path in IE browser, we could enable the security setting in Internet Explorer (open **Internet Options**, select **Security** tab, click the "**Custom level...**", **enable** the "**Include local directory path when uploading files to a server**" option and click **OK** button to save the change), after that we could use the value property to get the upload file full path, then, you could according to it to get the folder.

[**Note**]**Providing the full file path is regarded as a security vulnerability and is by default disabled**. For security considerations, I suggest you not enable this option and use this method to display the folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose only folders with input tag in html but in the end it will select all the files in that folder and there is no way you could get the file path in modern browsers(for security reasons). JS does'nt communicate with file system.

but if your primary concern is for users to select folders only, you can use this:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That won't work. They specifically asked about Internet Explorer which doesn't support that. (They also specially asked to read the directory path, not the files).

Comment: Its works in IE. please open this codepen example in IE and check [link](https://codepen.io/MAccelar8/pen/gOpemro?editors=1111). I also agreed to the fact that JS wont communicate with the filesystem so you wont get the absolute path.

Comment: It says: *⚠ Unsupported Browser ⚠

CodePen probably won't work great in Internet Explorer 11. We generally only support the recent versions of major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Edge* … and won't let me see the demo. Looks like you didn't test it in IE yourself.

Comment: My apologies I had tested it in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 not IE.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put an empty attributes for your input type file

```
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

Comment: It then suggests to upload files instead of selecting a folder